# Cannot disable Hyper-V in Windows 10 64bit

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I want to disable Hyper-V, but when I go to Windows Features, untick Hyper-V and click OK. It asks me to Restart my computer, and I let it do a restart.

During the restart, it says it failed to apply the changes, and it says undoing changes. When I'm logged back into the computer, I can see that the Hyper-V is still ticked in Windows Features.

My Hyper-V manager looks like this:

[image: hyper-v]

I've read others threads, and they say there might be network stuff still hanging about, but I can't see anything Hyper-V related in Network and Sharing Center that is enabled.

[image: network]

As you can see, anything hyper-v is disabled, yet I still cannot disable hyper-v.

Comment: You can *disable* Hyper-V by stoppping the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service and setting it to disabled.

Comment: @AndrewMorton how do I go about stopping the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service?

Comment: @J86 Press the Windows key. Type `services` and "Services Desktop app" should be highlighted as the "Best match". Press Enter to open it. Find the service, right-click it and choose "Properties".

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton, it looks like it is already stopped. https://www.screencast.com/t/9kMDQ1FnruK. But I want that ticket to be off in Windows Features, I want to uninstall all Hyper-V stuff.

Comment: Depending on what you’re trying to accomplish, simply disabling the hypervisor (using `bcdedit`) may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before. I think the issue was that I used another virtualization application without disabling Hyper-V first and it damaged some of Hyper-V's files. So when Windows goes to remove Hyper-V it has trouble and rolls back the disable.

What worked for me is re-enabling Hyper-V to repair all its files:

1. Go to Windows Features and disable Hyper-V, but don't restart your computer
2. Go back to Windows Features again and enable Hyper-V
3. Restart your computer
4. Go to Windows Features and disable Hyper-V
5. Restart your computer for the last time

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyMansour, sadly it still didn't work. After trying all your steps, on the last restart,  I [get this](https://imgur.com/a/CmtgSAO).